# Help understanding the proof of Laplace multiplication axiom

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is a proof for the Laplace multiplication axiom:

$$\mathcal{L}[tf(t)](s) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}[f](s).$$

The proof is

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}[tf(t)](s) &= \int_0^{\infty} f(t)te^{-st}dt \\
&= -\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial s} e^{-st}dt \\
&= \frac{d}{ds} \int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st} dt \\
&= \frac{d}{ds} \mathcal{L}[f](s).
\end{aligned}$$

However I'm having difficulties understanding where the derivative $\frac{d}{ds}$ comes from.

Why is $t \cdot f(t) \cdot e^{-st} = -\frac{d}{ds} f(t) \cdot e^{-st}$ ?

I have no clue how to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(t)$ is a constant with respect to $t$, so

$$\frac{d}{ds}f(t)e^{-st} = f(t)\frac{d}{ds} e^{-st} = f(t)\cdot (-t\cdot e^{-st})$$

In the last step, I used the chain rule. If $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=-t\cdot x$, then $f(g(t))= e^{-st}$ and $$\frac{d}{ds}(f(g(s)) = \frac{df}{ds}(g(s))\cdot \frac{dg}{ds}(s) = e^{g(s)}\cdot (-t) = -t\cdot e^{-st}$$